# All ng commands are not working

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have tried uninstalling angular/cli and reinstalling it.

However `npm start` successfully runs the server by calling ng serve, but the problem is when, I have to create a component or a service by using `ng` commands.

[image]

Comment: Is it regarding angular 2 or angualr 4?

Comment: Now it is angular4. But for angular2 also this persists